# When should you specify PAD_INDEX?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, index

So, you can use `FILLFACTOR` to leave space in leaf index pages. Specifying `PAD_INDEX` also leaves space in intermediate nodes. What scenarios should you specify `PAD_INDEX`, and what benefit does it provide to the index?

Answer (score 11):

From Kimberly Tripp's post:

> Typically, PAD_INDEX is not needed unless you have extremely unbalanced activity and are unable to rebalance the tree (meaning you need to achieve high availability).

Read more: http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/KIMBERLY/post/MSDN-Webcast-QA-Index-Defrag-Best-Practices-Fragmentation-Questions-Part-I.aspx

What she means by high availability is that you don't have the ability to run index maintenance jobs that would lock the table.  Personally, I wouldn't recommend ever setting this by default - leave it to DBAs who find that they're unable to manage index maintenance appropriately with any other methods, like using [Ola Hallengren's maintenance scripts](http://ola.hallengren.com) during off hours.  His scripts are genius - they'll do as much as possible online.

Comment: How would `PAD_INDEX` help if you are unable to regularly rebuild the index to enforce the `FILLFACTOR` on the non-leaf nodes of the index in the first place?

Comment: You rebuild it less often, but with much more free space available.